# Facebook send dialog goes to feed view after sending

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

I am having some trouble with the [Facebook send dialog](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/send-dialog), using the Facebook Javascript SDK. The following code works exactly as intended on my local environment; sending the link and closing the popup, calling the callback.

In production, however, while the link is still sent to the specified user, instead of closing the popup window remains open and goes to to a Facebook feed view, never calling the callback.

```
FB.ui({
    app_id: '<app-id>',
    method: 'send',
    link: '{{ url()->current() }}', // provided by Laravel
}, (res) => {
    if(res.success) {
        // do things
    }
});
```

Any idea what I might be doing wrong? I have tried forcing `type: 'popup'` and providing a `redirect_uri`(although that is really not preferable, since I need the callback), but nothing has worked so far.

Comment: _“since I need the callback”_ – what for? Hope you are aware that “forcing” users to send something, or to gate content behind it, is not allowed.

Comment: @CBroe The product is a job ad service, and the send dialog is used to refer friends to job applications. The callback is used to submit a form, in order to know when a user has referred someone. No one is forced, and nothing is gated!

Comment: Is there even any `res.success` set, ever? According to the documentation, this dialog does not give any response data to begin with.

Comment: @CBroe Yes, the callback is fired with a res object (containing only the key "success") when I run it on my local server.